# How to increase accuracy of model using catboost

Tags: machine-learning, classification, catboost

I am trying to build a model for binary classification using catboost for a employee salary dataset. I have tried utmost tuning but still i am getting only 87% accuracy how can i increase it to ~98% or more?

Goal is to predict the class.

Here is the dataset and code:

Dataset:

http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Adult

Code:

```
    from catboost import CatBoostClassifier

    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    from numpy import arange
    from tqdm import tqdm_notebook as tqdm
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    plt.style.use('ggplot')
    import seaborn as sns
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    from sklearn import metrics, preprocessing

    train = pd.read_csv('train.csv')
    test = pd.read_csv('test.csv')

    X = train.drop('class', axis=1)
    y = train['class']

    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=27)
    test_data = test.drop('class', axis=1)
    print(y_train.value_counts())
    print(y_test.value_counts())


    #provide categorical features to catboost
    cat_features = ['workclass','education','marital-status','occupation','relationship','race','sex','native-country']

    best_params = {
            'bagging_temperature': 0.5,
            'depth': 8,
            'iterations': 1000,
            'l2_leaf_reg': 25,
            'learning_rate': 0.05,
            'sampling_frequency': 'PerTreeLevel',
            'leaf_estimation_method': 'Gradient',
            'random_strength': 0.8,
            'boosting_type': 'Ordered',
            'feature_border_type': 'MaxLogSum',
            'l2_leaf_reg': 50,
            'max_ctr_complexity': 2,
            'fold_len_multiplier': 2
    }

    model_cat = CatBoostClassifier(**best_params,
                               loss_function='Logloss',
                               eval_metric='AUC',
                               nan_mode='Min',
                               thread_count=8,
                               task_type='CPU',
                               verbose=True)


    model_cat.fit(X_train, y_train,
                              eval_set=(X_test, y_test),
                              cat_features=cat_features,
                              verbose_eval=300,
                              early_stopping_rounds=500,
                              use_best_model=True,
                              plot=False)


    model_cat.save_model("catmodel")

    ##Predictions
    cat_predictions = model_cat.predict_proba(test_data)[:, 1]
    cat_predictions_df = pd.DataFrame({'class': cat_predictions})
```

Here is the max accuracy i got after entire tuning..

```
     Test set class grouping:
     <=50K    7451
     >50K     2318

      Predicted
       Y    N
    [[7037  799]
     [ 414 1519]]

    Precision:  0.9444369883237149
    Recall:  0.8980347115875447
    Accuracy:  0.8758317125601393
    F1-score:  0.9206515339831229
```

So here still i have 414 FPs and 799 FNs which are bad results.. tried out all the best_params from documentation and different values of it.

Answer (score 3):

@MJ209, Here is the grid search params and accuracy.

```
    params = {'depth':[3,1,2,6,4,5,7,8,9,10],
              'iterations':[250,100,500,1000],
              'learning_rate':[0.03,0.001,0.01,0.1,0.2,0.3],
              'l2_leaf_reg':[3,1,5,10,100],
              'border_count':[32,5,10,20,50,100,200],
              'bagging_temperature':[0.03,0.09,0.25,0.75],
              'random_strength':[0.2,0.5,0.8],
              'max_ctr_complexity':[1,2,3,4,5] }


    model = CatBoostClassifier()
    grid_search_result = model.grid_search(params,
                                           X=train_set,
                                           y=train_label,
                                           cv=5,
                                           partition_random_seed=3,
                                           stratified=True)
```

i have stopped program in middle after 36 hrs of running as it shows it will take 24 days more to complete and below is the last trace of program:

150625: loss: 0.2800770 best: 0.2746405 (5345)    total: 7m 22s   remaining: 24d 1h 2m 7s

Answer (score 2):

I hope you can tune it further using **grid_search** method available in ***catboost.CatBoostClassifier*** library.

for more reference please find the URL: https://catboost.ai/docs/concepts/python-reference_catboost_grid_search.html

Comment: Hi @MJ029, i have tried out what you said but it leaves me with the worst results and taken long time. i have followed this [link](https://effectiveml.com/using-grid-search-to-optimise-catboost-parameters.html), still any idea how to get best accuracy with catboost ?

Comment: Hi @Hariram Manohar, can you please share me the grid search params and accuracy got in that ?